# Segmented Display With SMD Pads? (Not Thru-Hole or Half-hole SMD)

Tags: design, lcd, physical-design

I'm looking through a product design, and I've seen these SMD / sticky segmented displays LCD being used.

They are not hand-soldered, the segmented display appears to use some conductive sticky pad that attaches the pads on the board that have the common & signals going to the LCD.

Do you know what this is called specifically?  I've used typical thru-hole segmented displays, and I see that you can get like half-hole module type displays.

Anyone know the term of display that you just stick on the board?

(The white part is actually the backlight, and then the LCD display just goes on top and connects to those rectangular vertical pads circled in red).

[image]

Comment: Zebra connectors, alright.  Cool. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastomeric_connector  -- God speed, internet.

Comment: These are probably factory orderable only, not available through distributors (ok maybe alibaba if you consider that a distributor)

Comment: Yeah I agree.  You probably custom fabricate these (which is what I am looking for).  Our current LCD factory didn't know what these are / don't fabricate these.